# How many bytes is a Javascript Symbol

Tags: javascript, types, symbols

How big is a Javascript Symbol in bytes? Is there a well-defined size? Where did you find this info; can I get a reference?

Comment: Most likely the same as any object: a pointer to a data structure.

Comment: You could look up the internal data structure that various javascript engines use to represent a symbol. The number of bytes will depend on the implementation

Comment: Since a symbol can have a comment, it can be larger than a string.

Comment: @IlyaBursov, looks like you mix `Symbol` and `String`.

Comment: @VasylMoskalov probably, what is symbol then?

Comment: @IlyaBursov. From MDN: 
_The data type "symbol" is a primitive data type having the quality that, values of this type can be used to make object properties that are anonymous. < skip a bit>  In the JavaScript run-time environment, a symbol value is created by invoking the function `Symbol()`, which dynamically produces an anonymous, unique value_

Comment: @VasylMoskalov got it, thank you